# How to navigate to a Screen without adding it to backstack?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

My Navigator is:

```
const MyStack = createStackNavigator();

const MyRoutes= () => (
  <MyStack.Navigator headerMode='none' initialRouteName='First'>
    <MyStack.Screen name='First' component={ScreenFirst} />
    <MyStack.Screen name='Second' component={ScreenSecond} />
  </MyStack.Navigator>
);
```

My actual flow is:

```
First -> (next) -> Second -> (back) -> First
```

But I want to show the `First` route without adding it to the backstack, so it would be:

```
First -> (next) -> Second -> (back) -> (default OS behavior)
```

Is it possible? If yes, how? I am using `"@react-navigation/native": "^5.6.1"`.

I know I can control the Back behavior in `Second` route but since in Android (Java/Kotlin) it is possible to show a Fragment without adding it to the backstack, I suppose something similar exists in React Native.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `navigation.replace('Second')`. More info here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-actions#replace.